# I save form data using hook_form_alter() but the data don't appear when editing the node from the UI

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I implemented `hook_form_alter()` to insert few fields. I implemented `hook_node_insert()` to save the field data, `hook_node_load()`, and `hook_node_view()`.

Everything works fine, but when I edit the node, the edit form appears with no data.

How can I fix this?

```
function mymodule_form_ABC_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $options_first = _mymodule_get_first_dropdown_options();
  $selected = isset($form_state['values']['filed_1']) ? $form_state['values']['field_1'] : key($options_first);

  $form['field_1'] = array(
    // …
  );
  $form['field_2'] = array(
    // …
  );

  return $form;    
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_insert().
 */
function mymodule_node_insert($node) {    
    db_insert('my_custom_table')
      ->fields(array('nid' => $node->nid, 'field_1' => $node->field_1, 'field_2' => $node->field_2,))
      ->execute();
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_load().
 */
function mymodule_node_load($nodes, $types) {
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $nids[] = $node->nid;
  }

  $result = db_select('custom_table', 'e')
    ->fields('e', array('nid', 'filed_1', 'field_2'))
    ->where('e.nid IN (:nids)', array(':nids' => $nids))
    ->execute();

  foreach ($result as $record) {
    $nodes[$record->nid]->field_1 = $record->field_1;
    $nodes[$record->nid]->field_2 = $record->field_2;
  }
}


/**
 * Implements hook_node_update().
 */
function mymodule_node_update($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'abc') {
    // Delete the existing values.
    db_delete('custom_table')
      ->condition('nid', $node->nid)
      ->execute();

    db_insert('custom_table')
      ->fields(array('nid' => $node->nid, 'field_1' => $node->field_1, 'field_2' => $node->field_2,))
      ->execute();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code does is similar to what the Book module does with [book_form_node_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!book!book.module/function/book_form_node_form_alter/7), [book_node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!book!book.module/function/book_node_load/7), and [book_node_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!book!book.module/function/book_node_insert/7).

What is wrong in your code is that:

- In `mymodule_form_ABC_node_form_alter()`, you don't initialize the form fields from the values you loaded with `mymodule_node_load()`, which means the form fields you are using are always set to an empty string. The Book module uses `$form_state['values']['book']` to initialize `$node->book`, but the comment on [_book_add_form_elements()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!book!book.module/function/_book_add_form_elements/7) explains why that is done.

  ```
  // If the form is being processed during the Ajax callback of our book bid
  // dropdown, then $form_state will hold the value that was selected.
  if (isset($form_state['values']['book'])) {
    $node->book = $form_state['values']['book'];
  }
  ```
- You implement [hook_node_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7), but not [hook_node_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7). This means the value of the node properties you are using are saved when a node is created, not when a node is updated.

It is true that the Book module implements [hook_node_prepare()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_prepare/7) ([book_node_prepare()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!book!book.module/function/book_node_prepare/7)), but its purpose is only setting the default value for the node properties it handles, which is useful in the case a node is not created through the user interface.

Since you are interested in saving those node properties when the content type is *abc*, I would implement the code as follows.

```
function mymodule_form_abc_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $node = $form['#node'];
  $options_first = _mymodule_get_first_dropdown_options();
  $selected = !empty($node->field_1) ? $node->field_1 : key($options_first);

  $form['field_1'] = array(
    // …
  );
  $form['field_2'] = array(
    // …
  );

  return $form;    
}

function mymodule_node_prepare($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'abc') {
    $node->field_1 = '';
    $node->field_2 = '';
  }
}

function mymodule_node_load($nodes, $types) {
  $nids = array();

  foreach ($nodes as $nid => $node) {
    if ($node->type == 'abc') {
      $nids[] = $nid;
    }
  }

  if (!empty($nids)) {
    db_query('SELECT e.nid, e.field_1, e.field_2 FROM {custom_table} e WHERE e.nid IN :nids'), array(':nids' => $nids), array('fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

    foreach ($result as $record) {
      $nodes[$record['nid']]->field_1 = $record['field_1'];
      $nodes[$record['nid']]->field_2 = $record['field_2'];
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_insert().
 */
function mymodule_node_insert($node) {
  // hook_node_insert() is called for any node.
  // Check the content type of the node is the one for which the form fields have been added.
  if ($node->type == 'abc') {
    $values['field_1'] = !empty($node->field_1) ? $node->field_1 : '';
    $values['field_2'] = !empty($node->field_2) ? $node->field_2 : '';

    db_insert('my_custom_table')
      ->fields(array('nid' => $node->nid, 'field_1' => $values['field_1'], 'field_2' => $values['field_2']))
      ->execute();
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_update().
 */
function mymodule_node_update($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'abc') {
    db_update('custom_table')
      ->condition('nid' => $node->nid)
      ->fields(array('field_1' => $node->field_1, 'field_2' => $node->field_2))
      ->execute();
  }
}
```

Dynamic queries should be used when strictly necessary, for example because another module alters them. If you need to use a dynamic query, I would rather rewrite it as the following one.

```
$result = db_select('custom_table', 'e')
  ->fields('e', array('nid', 'filed_1', 'field_2'))
  ->condition('nid', $nids, 'IN')
  ->execute();
```

To update the values in a database, you should use [db_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_update/7), not deleting the values already present in the database, and inserting the new values. `db_update()` looks for the database rows matching the condition expressed in `$query->condition()`, and updates the fields given in `$query->fields()` with the new values.

As side note, if you are editing a module that is already installed, and enabled, you need to disable, and re-enable it, or Drupal will not notice the code has been changed, and it implements new hooks. Drupal keeps the list of implemented hooks from the enabled modules in cache; disabling a module, and re-enabling it, forces Drupal to update that cache.

Comment: thanks you very much for such a detailed answer kiamlaluno. you mean that i need to implement hook_node_prepare().but when i do that i can see all values in node object by doing krumo($node). but point here is how to assign them to form fields.

Comment: I mean that you need to implement `hook_node_update()`, since `hook_node_insert()` is invoked only for nodes that are created. `hook_node_prepare()` is useful when nodes are not created through the user interface. Implementing it is useful, but for the issue you are having `hook_node_update()` is the hook you should implement.

Comment: i have implemented that as well but what it actually do is just update the custom_table if the values are changed. how can i make it show those values in the form (form which we are editing). i have updated the question with the new code at the end. thnaks

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: hi Kiamlaluno, all working great now apart from this callback function. when i change value of field1, other fields(field2 to field5) suppose to change but they are not in this case. please see if you can help. thanks

Comment: That is a different question that requires a new question. Please don't reuse questions to ask new questions once you get an answer for your old question. (I said _question_ too much times, didn't I?)

Comment: i am sorry but it was linked to this answer thats why i put it here. anyway i am still struggling with this if you can have a look please. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51666/dependent-dropdown-select-callback-function-not-working

Answer (score 1):

You need implement [hook_node_prepare](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_prepare/7). This hook is used to load additional data before a node object is shown on the add/edit form.

Comment: thanks for your help Eugene. but i am still having problems suing hook_node_prepare but no luck.  i have updated my question with the code. please have a look. thanks

Comment: I don't see implementation of hook_node_prepare in your code

Comment: thanks Eugene. i have done that locally and in the node object i can see the required values for example $node->field_1 and $node->field_2. but i dont know how to assign them to form fields as there is no form_state object available here.

Comment: You need assign these values in hook_form_alter $form['field_1']['#default_value] = $form_state['node']->field_1;

Comment: do i need to create a new hook_form_alter or the the one i already have. mymodule_form_ABC_node_form_alter(). $node object is not available in the hook_form_alter is it?

Comment: Node object is located inside $form_state array